# Qual código coloco com o while?

Tags: java, eclipse, if, while

quero que tenha um loop quando for digitado o numero referente a "sim"; ja tentei com os codigos: `while(resp.equals(cont))` e  `while(!1.equals(cont))` .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class umm_whilezinho {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int qtf = 0;
        int qtm = 0;
        String gen;
        int cont = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Qual o seu gênero? (Feminino ou masculino) ");
        gen = in.next();
        
        while(!1.equals(cont))  {
        if(gen == ("feminino")) {
            ++qtf;
        if(gen ==("Feminino"));
            ++qtf;
        if(gen == ("Masculino")) 
            ++qtm;
        if(gen == ("masculino")) 
            ++qtm;
        }
        System.out.println("Deseja adicionar mais uma pessoa? (Sim  =  1, Não = 2)");
        cont = in.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Quantidade de mulheres: "+qtf);
        System.out.println("Quantidade de homens: "+qtm);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Levando em consideração que a leitura será feita pelo menos uma vez, você pode colocar o trecho de código que você quer repetir dentro de uma estrutura de repetição *do while*, com a condição `while(cont == 1)`.

A condição que você usou não funcionou porque a função *equals* só é usada para comparar uma *String* com outra, e a variável *cont* é do tipo inteiro.

Além disso, as comparações feitas dentro da repetição para atualizar as variáveis de contagem não precisam ser repetidas. Você pode transformar a *string* lida em uma palavra com todos os caracteres minúsculos (ou com todos os caracteres minúsculos, tanto faz do ponto de vista da lógica) usando a função *toLowerCase*. Isso elimina a necessidade de serem feitas múltiplas comparações. E as comparações estavam sendo feitas usando o operador *==*, sendo que em Java, como já disse, *strings* devem ser comparadas usando a função *equals*. O código completo fica:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int qtf = 0;
        int qtm = 0;
        String gen;
        int cont = 0;
        do
        {
          System.out.println("Qual o seu gênero? (Feminino ou masculino) ");
          gen = in.next();
          
          if(gen.toLowerCase().equals("feminino")) 
              ++qtf;
          if(gen.toLowerCase().equals("masculino")) 
              ++qtm;
          
            System.out.println("Deseja adicionar mais uma pessoa? (Sim  =  1, Não = 2)");
            cont = in.nextInt();
          
        }while(cont == 1);
        
        System.out.println("Quantidade de mulheres: "+qtf);
        System.out.println("Quantidade de homens: "+qtm);
}
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it (alterei o nome da classe para Main, mas é só alterar para o nome original no seu código)](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/AmbitiousBrokenEntropy#Main.java)

Comment: agora eu entendi, muito obrigada!